# Slide up animation in recyclerview items

Tags: android, animation, android-recyclerview

I am working on an android app and using recycleview inside a fragment. I am having a number of items in this recycleview and having a option to delete the items as well from recyclerview.

I want that when I delete any item, it should be removed from the recyclerview and the lower item should have a effect of slide up, so that the users can see that the current item has been removed and the next item now takes the position of last item.

So, I want to apply slide up effect on the recyclerview item. Please help me if anyone know how can I do this.

Thanks a lot in advanced. :)

Comment: https://github.com/wasabeef/recyclerview-animators use this library

Comment: did you call `notifyItemRemoved()` after removing item ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just call notifyItemRemoved(position) with the position of the removed item and the recycler view will automatically show the animation.

Comment: Thank you so much notifyItemRemoved is giving me the animation which I want. Thanks a lot. :) :)